# _cipher.doFinal() behaves differently on Windows and Linux

Tags: java, encryption

I need some suggestions on below mentioned java statement.

```
String strCipherStr = 
    new String_cipher.doFinal(
        Base64.decodeBase64(
            encryptedStr.getBytes("UTF-8"))), "UTF-8");
```

This statement gives different output on Windows and Linux.  On windows it throws error `javax.crypto.BadPaddingException` and in Linux, no exception. I have checked JCE but version is same on both environment.

Appreciate your help!

Comment: This code does not compile. And what is `String_cipher`?

Comment: javax.crypto.Cipher



This class provides the functionality of a cryptographic cipher for encryption and decryption. It forms the core of the Java Cryptographic Extension (JCE) framework.

Answer (score 0):

I would look at your `CLASSPATH` environment variable settings; The javax.crypto package may not be in the right place on Windows.

Comment: I need same exception on both environement because - I am trying implement test case to decrypt blank string.String dstr = _decrypter.decrypt("");